# Robot framework, Python - handle lazy load on page with dynamic content

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, lazy-loading, robotframework

I have a page with dynamically generated table (**rows are dynamically generated**). In my test **I do NOT know how many rows to expect**. I just create a dictionary from all the rows and then compare to another dictionary. 
But the table has lazy load, so when the number of rows is higher, some of the **rows which should be there are not visible** "on the first sight" but it needs to be scrolled down to get them. So those rows are not included into my dictionary and then it fails...
But again, I do not know when to scroll (if the table has small amount of rows, there is nowhere to scroll) and where to scroll (I do not expect any particular element), how many rows to expect etc.

Does anyone has an idea how to handle situation like this? Because I don't. 
 :-( Thank you!

Comment: Simply read all rows and scroll in a loop until the last element is equal to the last element from previous iteration.

Comment: When you scroll, do the new records get added to the table, or are they replacing the old ones?

Comment: The visible "frame" of the table is still the same - like 30 rows, so during scrolling the rows are "replaced"

Comment: Hey @neliCZka, were you able to figure this part out? I am also stuck at same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to solve this problem as below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

# Get the current number of rows
current_rows_number = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr'))
while True:
    # Scroll down to make new XHR (request more table rows)
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)
    try:
        # Wait until number of rows increased       
        wait(driver, 5).until(lambda: len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr')) > current_rows_number)
        # Update variable with current rows number
        current_rows_number = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr'))
    # If number of rows remains the same after 5 seconds passed, break the loop
    # as there no more rows to receive
    except TimeoutException:
        break

# Now you can scrape the entire table
```

*P.S. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with `RobotFramework`, so above code is on pure `Selenium` + `Python`. I hope it can be easily interpreted :)*

Comment: thanks, it can be easily called from Robot..I'll try...just as I am looking at the code, I am not sure about use of END, because in that case it is scrolled down to the last rows of the table, but the "middle rows" will be still missing in the dictionary I guess...but I'll try and will see