# Not complete list of children in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get all children of one element.
The structure of the html is like below.

[html structure img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUAxU.png)

I wrote code like this.

```
time.sleep(30)
stocks = browser.find_element_by_class_name("CI-GRID-BODY-TABLE-TBODY")
stock_list = stocks.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")

for stock in stock_list:
    print(stock.text)
```

It prints only 14 children though it has a total of 200 children.
I think 30 seconds is enough for running javascript to fill the whole table.

When I print out the length of stock_list, it shows 200, but it shows only 14 items on the screen.

Do you have any idea for this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print all the child elements, you can use a cssSelector:

```
stocks.find_elements_by_css_selector("*")
```

Comment: I think this will return all *descendants*, but not *children*

Comment: I also tried this, but got only 14 items printed. I guess this is because the table component that I want to retrieve has 14 items initially when not scrolled. How can I retrieve total items including scrolled down items.

Comment: @KyuhanNam , you can try to modify and implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569549/robot-framework-python-handle-lazy-load-on-page-with-dynamic-content/44570402#44570402)

Comment: @Andersson you are correct, that code will return not only the children but all the descendants as well. Thanks for pointing that out